# Как ограничить просмотр видеоролика по времени?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, видео

Как разрешить просмотр полных видеороликов с сайта только тем, кто купил абонемент?

Люди, не имеющие абонемента, смогут просматривать видео только 20 секунд. Как лучше всего решить? Т.е как обрезать видеоролики по времени?

Пока что только одна идея: загружать два варианта ролика – обрезанный и полный, и, в зависимости от статуса пользователя, отдавать тот или иной.

Думаю, есть какие-то более оптимальные решения, чтобы не резать видео, а просто останавливать возможность просмотра после 20 сек.

Comment: Делать что-то надо на стороне сервера. на стороне клиента (`javascript` `jquery`) все будет сломано.

Comment: @akasergej "а просто останавливать возможность просмотра после 20 сек" А что мне мешает скачать полный вариант? Ссылку в коде я найду

Answer (score 5):

Сервер должен ограничить длительность. Варианты:

- Загружать 2 файла - надёжно, не создаёт сложностей и не увеличивает загрузку сервера. Требует больше места на сервере.
- Загружать полный файл, обрезать на сервере при скачивании. Удобно, не надо грузить 2 файла, не надо обрезать файл самому. Для большинства форматов это может вызвать существенную нагрузку на сервер. Нужен эффективный код для обрезки.
- Загружать полный файл, обрезать на сервере при загрузке. Удобно, не надо грузить 2 файла, не надо обрезать файл самому. Нужен код для обрезки.
- Загружать полный файл, но в формате, позволяющем резать файл в произвольных местах. Запоминать позицию лимита (номер байта) и для простых пользователей отдавать префикс файла. Вроде все хорошо, кроме того, что такой формат надо подобрать и всё в него сконвертировать. Плюс, остаётся вопрос о способе определения байта в файле.
- Использовать специальные steaming-протоколы. Этот вариант оставлю без комментариев.

Любые попытки реализовать ограничение на клиенте позволят достать с сервера весь файл и просмотреть видео оффлайново.

Answer (score 1):

Не пробовал, и это не php решение. [nginx умеет](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_mp4_module.html) раздавать пседво-потоковое видео, а используемый для этого [h264 streaming module](http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki), в частности, позволяет создавать [виртуальные под-клипы](http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/VirtualVideoClipUrlRewrite) из длинного исходного файла.